# How to set alias table name in Laravel table model

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this query builder in Laravel:

```
$obj_table = MyTable::get();
```

Now, how to make my `MyTable` to have alias name?

The reason I need this, I need to use `with()` and `Joining` with my another tables.

Anyone got the same problems with me?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean alias? do you want the table name?

Answer (score 0):

From laravel documentaion

You may also alias the relationship count result, allowing multiple counts on the same relationship:

```
$posts = Post::withCount([
'comments',
'comments AS pending_comments' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('approved', false);
}
])->get();
```

For more information have a look at 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Cheers,
Hope this helps